# Bash command to replace text between two strings, multilines

Tags: bash, text

I'm trying to replace a multiline chunk of text between two known tags, inside a file. This has the following structure:

```
#STARTTAG
some text with numbers 123
and dots . that I want 
to replace .
#ENDTAG
```

I've been trying different approaches based on what I've seen online including sed, awk, perl, but I can't seem to make it work.

For instance, this is what I've been trying to implement:

```
sed -i '' 's/STARTTAG.*ENDTAG/alternative text/g' somefile
```

but it doesn't do anything. I tried adding ' and " to each string (i.e. the tags & replacement text) but it just does nothing. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Note that I would like both the text to be replaced and the alternative texts to be multiline.

Thank you

Comment: if you know the line numbers, you can use head, cat, and tail to paste the relative parts together in the new file. if you don't know the line numbers, you can find them using grep. if there are _multiple_ such tag-pairs, you can use a `while read -r` loop to append to a string line-by-line up until the token, at which point you add your alternative string, and skip copying until the end tag appears.

Comment: Please edit question and add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do:

```
sed '/STARTTAG/,/ENDTAG/{s/.*/alternative text/g;q}' file
```

yields:

```
alternative text
```

The `q` command is to instruct `sed` to `q`uit.

`sed` is a line stream oriented tool, so it's purpose is not to process multilines easily for cases more complicated.

If you need to keep the tags, better use `awk` to not have a convoluted and non readable & maintenable `sed` command:

```
awk '
    BEGIN{p=1}
    $1=="#STARTTAG"{p=0;print;next}
    $1=="#ENDTAG"{print "alternative text";p=1}
    p
' file
```

```
#STARTTAG
alternative text
#ENDTAG
```

---

If you need to change the file *on the fly*, use `sponge` from `more-utils` (debian):

```
awk '...' file | sponge file
```

---

Another proper approach, is to use [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), then, the regex looks more natural:

```
perl -g -pe 's/(#STARTTAG).*?(#ENDTAG)/$1\nalternative text\n$2/s' file
```

`-g` require `Perl`'s >= `5.36`. If you have lower version, use `perl -0777` instead.

With this Perl's command, you can use `-i` switch like `sed`:

```
perl -i -g '...' file
```

---

```
LESS='+/^ +-g' perldoc perlrun
```

> `-g`
> undefines the input record separator ($/) and thus enables the
> slurp mode. In other words, it causes Perl to read whole files at once, instead of line by line.

Comment: I took the OP to mean that the text given in the question is a chunk of a larger file that should not otherwise be modified.  If that's indeed what they meant then your `sed` option does not serve, as it will lose the tail of the file.

Comment: Up to OP to use any of the various valid solutions I gave. I don't like `sed` for complicated tasks.

Comment: the perl command does the trick for me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is a line-based text processor. So, by default, your regular expression `STARTTAG.*ENDTAG` matches a single line like `fooSTARTTAGbarENDTAGbaz`, not a group of lines like the one you show.

Doing what you want with any POSIX `sed` is significantly more complex than with `awk`:

```
awk '/^#STARTTAG$/ {n = 1}
     n && /^#ENDTAG$/ {print "alternative text"; n = 0}
     /^#STARTTAG$/,/^#ENDTAG$/ {next} 1' file
```

For in-place replacement you'll need GNU `awk` and its `-i inplace` option:

```
awk -i inplace ...
```

Note: this will replace all occurrences of `#STARTTAG...#ENDTAG` blocks. To replace only the first one:

```
awk '/^#STARTTAG$/ {n += 1}
     n == 1 && /^#ENDTAG$/ {print "alternative text"; n += 1}
     /^#STARTTAG$/,/^#ENDTAG$/ {if(n <= 2) next} 1' file
```